# :first-child and :nth-child(1) not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the first paragraph of the "contacts" address element using nth-child(1) or first-child selectors (.contacts:first-child), but it's not working :( if i create a class to the first paragraph and use a class css selector, it works normally. What am i missing?

```
<div class="address-col">
    <p class="footer-heading">Contact us</p>
       <address class="contacts">
         <p>23 Harrison St., 2nd Floor, San Francisco, CA 94107</p>
    
         <p>
            <a class="footer-link" href="tel:415-201-6370">415-201-6370</a><br/>
            <a class="footer-link" href="mailto:hello@example.com">hello@example.com</a>
         </p>
       </address>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents the first element among a group of sibling elements.`

The correct selector is `.contacts p:first-child`

If you wanted it to work only based on the container and not know or care what it contains you could use `.contacts > *:first-child`

When you use it as you are on the container what you are actually asking for via css is an element with the class `.contacts` that is the first child among it's sibling elements.

Comment: you're right. i misunderstood the documentation. i tought i was selecting contacts first child, which is the first paragraph by using .contacts:first-child. thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome, glad I could help you on your road to better understanding of css! Have a great day and keep coding!